# What is the meaning of the Gerund?

Tags: grammar

I've read on the Internet that **the gerund** is a form of the verb, which serves to indicate an action in *the Present Perfect Tense* in English and Spanish.

What is the real meaning of **the gerund** in English?

In our country, we're taught that **the gerund** is *the mixture of a verb and a noun.*

Is that right?

Comment: [A gerund is a verbal that ends in -ing and functions as a noun](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/01/)

Comment: "A gerund is a verbal that ends in -ing and functions as a noun" isn't the best possible definition.

Answer (score 2):

Gerunds function as nouns in sentences.  So technically gerunds are nouns.

However, they can take subjects, objects, and complements like verbs.  The term *verbal* is used to describe words like these that live in a little of both worlds.  Infinitives and participles (I think) are other verbals.

Many people will say *-ing* words are verbs (and they aren't completely incorrect) but the only time they are *part* of a verb is when acting as a helping or auxillary verb with *be* or *have*.

I don't think it's correct to say any *-ing* word is a gerund either, because you can't  know until you know what function it's serving in a sentence.

> I've read on the Internet that the gerund is a form of the verb, which serves to indicate an action in the Present Perfect Tense in English and Spanish.

Consider this example:

> I am walking to the store.

*To be* + {-ing} is how English expresses the present *continuous* (not *perfect*) tense, which is the normal present tense used to describe things happening now.  *-ing* here is not a gerund.  I believe it's technically an adverb, but it's easier if you just consider *am walking* to be a two-word verb.

Present *perfect* tense uses *have* in English:

> I have walked to the store.

which AFAIK corresponds to *haber* + {past participle} in Spanish but you might want to check with https://spanish.stackexchange.com on that.

I did find [this](http://users.ipfw.edu/jehle/COURSES/GERUND.HTM) which seems to call any *-ndo* word in Spanish a gerund.  If this is a common thing taught in your country I believe there will be a conflict with a lot of information around that makes the above distinctions.  But I'm no expert on English educational literature or websites so I could be wrong.  Hopefully the above helps, though.

Spanish I think will use the infinitive where a lot of times in English the *-ing* form of the word is used.

> Walking helps me stay fit = *Caminar ayuda a mantenerme en forma* (from Google Translate)

In English, you could say this:

> To walk helps me stay fit

but it sounds weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence about the nature of a gerund is of very low quality, or rather it is simply wrong. The gerund is a verbform with the ending -ing, just as the present participle, and it has the nature of a verb and a noun.

The gerund has four forms, two active and two passive forms:  doing, having  done,  being printed, having been printed.

The gerund has two difficulties, one being its double nature of having verbal and noun character, the second difficulty being that gerund and present participle have the same form.